# Is there any predefined global function in Lightning Component to detect IE 11 browser?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, browser, ie-11

I'm looking for a way to identify if client browser is `IE 11` or any other browser.

Can anyone suggest how can I do this kind of detection?

I'm familiar with `$Browser.formFactor` global function in Lightning Component, but this does not detect browser type, and only Device type is detected.

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to detect if a browser is IE 11 or not. Browsers can lie about what they are, usually at the behest of the user. Instead, perform [feature detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/Feature_detection) if you're interested in a particular feature. This is more reliable than determining if a browser is a particular version.

Lightning does not have any means of determining IE 11 versus other browsers for this reason. You can use the [$Browser](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_browser_value_provider.htm) value provider to determine if you're on a Windows, iOS, or Android phone, or if you're running on a phone, tablet, or full-sized device.

Comment: Feature detection is a good idea, thanks for suggesting it. `$Browser` was not helpful for me as it's great for device detection but not browsers, and ironically, the global function is named Browser :-)

Comment: @VarunC Yeah, I think it really should have been something more like $OS or $Device, because that's really what it does.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard function to detect the browser. We can detect browser in below ways.

1. By doing an SOQL in LoginHistory on the landing page.
2. Writing a login flow and detect the browser.
3. Write JavaScript to detect browser at the client side. see example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)