# Detect if a Lightning component is opened from Chrome

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'd like to detect if a lightning component is opened from Chrome browser.
I've tried using `$A.get('$Browser')`but it doesn't provide anything about detecting Chrome. Do you know how i could achieve this?
Thanks,

**EDIT** : It's not about detecting any browser, os or device, it's about detecting when Salesforce1 is actually running on Chrome Mobile Browser or using Web-view specifically.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to know if it's Chrome or not? You should be using [feature detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Cross_browser_testing/Feature_detection) to determine if a specific feature is available. For that matter, [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) should give you all the details you need if you want advanced feature detection.

Comment: Actually my main goal is to provide a different UX from Salesforce1 web view and any mobile browser (IE, Firefox, Chrome). But i've noticed that an `isChrome` property was not present from lightning global variable `$A.get('$Browser')`

Comment: Check solution in post https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/240783/how-to-detect-browser-in-lightning-component-for-desktop-and-mobile-both

Comment: As i mentionned in my question, i've checked `$A.get('$Browser')` and indeed it enables to detect Firefox, IE but not Chrome specifically. The only information we have is about `isAndroid = true` but that is not reliable to deduct if the user is actually using Chrome on Mobile or Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

The $Browser global value provider returns information about the hardware and operating system of the browser accessing the application.

`$A.get('$Browser')` is used to detect the OS and/or the hardware(Desktop/Mobile/Tablet).

To get the information about the web browser, follow the [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/240783/how-to-detect-browser-in-lightning-component-for-desktop-and-mobile-both)